# replacing values in Vector1 with values from Vector2, conditional on values in Vector3

Tags: r

I am very new to using R, so please go easy on me.

I am working with data from a survey that was administered twice to roughly the same group of respondents. Among other things, the survey asked respondents to list their height.

Before the survey was administered for a second round, some of the original wave-one respondents left the sample, and some new respondents arrived. When the survey was administered a second time, it began with a filter question that asked whether the respondent had taken the survey before. Respondents who took the first survey were not asked about their height on the second survey, but "new" respondents were asked about their height.

I am trying to create a variable that represents the height of all respondents who participated in the wave-two survey. Because respondents who took the wave-one survey have missing data for the wave-two height question, I need to replace these missing values with their values from the wave-one survey.

I realize this is probably an easy fix, but I am not sure how to do it. My data:

**Height.W1** = A vector containing the height in feet for respondents who took the first survey.

**Height.W2** = A similar variable for respondents who took the second survey.

**Interview.Status** = A variable indicating whether the respondent took the first survey. Let's say a value of "1" means the respondent took the first survey, and therefore has missing data for the Height.W2 variable.

How can I replace values for Height.W2 with values from Height.W1, conditional on whether Interview.Status==1?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you place a snippet of your code here to share the data another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly:

Making some data to work with, some with `Interview.Status == 1`, and some with `Interview.Status==0`.

```
> df <- structure(list(Height.W1 = c(60, 62, 58, 64), Height.W2 = c(60, NA, 58, NA), Interview.Status = c(0, 1, 0, 1)), .Names = c("Height.W1", "Height.W2", "Interview.Status"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
> df
  Height.W1 Height.W2 Interview.Status
1        60        60                0
2        62        NA                1
3        58        58                0
4        64        NA                1
```

I subset by those with `Interview.Status == 1` and replace `Height.W2`, which is `NA`, with `Height.W1`.

```
> df$Height.W2[df$Interview.Status == 1] <- df$Height.W1[df$Interview.Status == 1]
> df
  Height.W1 Height.W2 Interview.Status
1        60        60                0
2        62        62                1
3        58        58                0
4        64        64                1
```

Comment: Awesome. This helped a bunch!

Comment: Glad to help.  Don't forget to accept one of the responses as the answer (the checkmark on the side). :)

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that `Height.W2` has `NA` for `Interview.Status==1`, but it is whether `Height.W1` has `NA` or not for `Interview.Status!=1`.  Assuming it has, a one-liner could be

```
Height <- apply(df[, c("Height.W1", "Height.W2")], 1, min, na.rm = T)
```

or `max`, `sum` or any other function for that matter.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. If I create a new vector by summing the contents of the two other vectors, then the missing data will be replaced with the relevant values. Thank you!